# JSP Only a type can be imported

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

So I'm trying to use Oracle's sample code here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/doc.1111/e17332/api002.htm#autoId91

It has the following to import classes:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@page import = "java.util.Vector" %>
<%@page import = "java.net.URL" %>
<%@page import = "java.util.Properties" %>
<%@page import = "java.util.HashMap" %>
import javax.xml.rpc.Stub;
<%@page import = "oracle.search.query.webservice.client.*" %>
```

As you can see the 6th line is not like the others. If I leave the code like this the page loads and the text from that line is just printed on the screen. If I change the line to be like the others:

```
<%@page import = "javax.xml.rpc.Stub" %>
```

I get the error:

```
Only a type can be imported. javax.xml.rpc.Stub resolves to a package.
```

The following also don't work:

```
<%@page import = "javax.xml.rpc.Stub;" %>
<%@page import = "javax.xml.rpc.Stub.*" %>
```

So how do I properly import this class?

Comment: Simply you are using wrong package name. Double check there is such package in your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
javax.xml.rpc.Stub
```

is not in the classpath.

I'm guessing that you are not actually using it in your page yet so it will just print

```
import javax.xml.rpc.Stub;
```

but won't import this Interface (as @page directive is missing).

BTW: This stub interface is contained in [jaxrpc-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api/1.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

That package is in a file called jaxrpc.jar; make sure that the file is on the classpath of your application.But writing java code and html code together is not recommended. Put your java code into javabeans.

Comment: Yes, do I have to copy jaxrpc.jar into my WEB-INFO/lib folder to get it to work?
I'm using this sample code to get familiar with the API, once I'm comfortable I do plan on separating the java and html.